# Word orders in sentences

Tags: word-order

> 1)The company has a debt of two million dollars left from last year.
>
> 2)You can buy everything you need ranging from clothing to food.
>
> 3)Did you see the man who resembles the general next to your friend .

In first and second sentences I asked if the word order is correct or not. But third sentence confuse me. I thougt there are a few meaning . it is not clear who is next to your friend general or the man .

Comment: The third sentence is ungrammatical; you can't say *_the your friend._ And if it's a question it needs a question mark. So it should confuse you. The first two are correct, but need punctuation (and are missing some words): _.. a debt of two million dollars **that was** left over .._ and _.. everything **that** you need, ranging from clothing to food._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two sentences are **exceptions** to the general rule that modifiers must be immediately adjacent to a noun being modified. This type of exception arises with respect to noun phrases.

In your first sentence, "left over from last year," the modifying participial phrase, is immediately adjacent to the noun phrase "debt of two million dollars," but it is not adjacent to the chief noun in that phrase, which is "debt."

Your second sentence has the same structure, the modifying participial phrase, "ranging from clothing to food, is immediately adjacent to the noun phrase "everything needed," but not to the phrase's only noun, "everything."

You are correct that the construction **may sometimes** lead to ambiguity although it is usually eliminated by context.

In your third sentence, there would be ambiguity only if your friend was in a place with more than one general and more than one man. If only one general was present, then "next to your friend" would be unnecessary to identify the general, but would be necessary to identify the otherwise unspecified man. If, however, there were several generals, the sentence would be ambiguous unless cured by context. Then you need to recast the sentence

> Did you see the man who was seated next to your friend and resembled the general?

The "and" now makes it clear that a man is being identified by two characteristics.

> Did you see the man who resembled that general who was seated next to your friend?

The two distinct uses of "who" and the isolating "that" now make clear that a man is being identified by one characteristic and that a general is being identified by a different characteristic.